# How do I manually trigger a buttons hover state in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, events

I need to trigger the hover state of a Flex button programatically, so that it looks like the user is hovering over it. There is a flex page about "Manually dispatching events":

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_07.html

Which would work, but what I'd really like to do is change the *style* of the button without having to throw an event. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason this wouldn't work?

```
button.setStyle('skin', button.getStyle('upSkin'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Flex 4x it is best to change the skin its self, this will do the trick.

```
 button.setStyle('skinClass', SkinClass);
```