# change state when hover on another spark element

Tags: apache-flex, hover, mouseover

How to set a hover state (upSkin) when hover on another element?
This example is not working on spark:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364244?tab=oldest#tab-top

Would like to do something like this:

```
<s:Button id="but1"/>
<s:Button label="change" mouseOver="button2_mouseOverHandler(event)"/>

protected function button2_mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
//make but1 look like I'm hovering it
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When mouse is over element A, you want element B to change style? Create event listeners for A (MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT). Or what?

Update: get skin object and set one of the four states: up, over, down, disabled (found in skin.states array):

```
var skin:ButtonSkin = ButtonSkin(button1.skin);
skin.setCurrentState("over");
```

Comment: but what should I do to make the button state hover?

Comment: I used this:var skin:AddButtonSkin = buttonId.skin as AddButtonSkin; skin.setCurrentState("over");